# How to release ADOX CoCatalog after creating a database?

Tags: c++, database, c++builder, adox

I create new MS Access database using the following (C++ Builder XE2):

```
CatalogPtr cat = CoCatalog::Create();
cat->Create(strConn.c_bstr());
```

The problem is that lock file is created and I want to delete it. I know I need to release the "cat" object but

```
cat->Release();
```

don't work and crashes my app. I also tried

```
cat->ActiveConnection = NULL;
```

before relase but no effect.. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call Release function, It automatically is called by CatalogPtr destructor.